# DataStax DSE Search: How to get hit Highlighting to work for Dynamic fields?

Tags: solr, highlight, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We are using local solr server successfully for long time. But now, due to high availability we wanted explore Datastax DSE search as an option.

Normal indexing and querying is working as expected. But hit highlight feature is working only for normal fields but not for 'dynamic fields'.

```
    q=<dynamic>_body:something
    fl=*<dynamic>_body, details, tags
    hl.fl=*
```

For the above simple query in Datastax solr dashboard doesn't work as expected. It returns highlight decorated entries for 'details', and 'tags' fields in highlights response but not for the 'dynamic_body' field (assuming that word 'something' is present in all the fields) . This query works as expected in local solr server dashboard.

Can someone let us know why this is failing for dynamic fields in Datastax solr ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known limitation and it will be addressed in short when 4.0.4 is available.

Regards